# How do I use Partitioned Tables in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I have never used partitioned table before. I just created an example to make sure whether I have understood about partitioned table correctly or not.
For example,

```
create table myfirstdataset.newtable(transaction_id int64,transaction_date date) partition by transaction_date
```

and the table contains the following rows

```
Row transaction_id  transaction_date     
1   1               2017-01-15   
2   2               2017-01-15   
3   3               2017-01-15   
4   4               2017-01-15   
5   1               2017-01-16   
6   1               2017-01-17   
7   1               2017-01-18   
8   1               2017-01-19   
9   3               2017-01-20   
10  4               2017-01-20   
11  6               2017-01-20   
12  5               2017-01-20
```

Here the table is partitioned by transaction_date column and 
there are 6 partitions called **2017-01-15**, **2017-01-16**, **2017-01-17**, **2017-01-18**, **2017-01-19**, **2017-01-20**.

Partitions **2017-01-15** and **2017-01-20** contains 4 rows, whereas other partitions contain only one row. Am I correct?

Comment: you are correct. why you ask? is there something that makes you think it is not correct?

Comment: I have never used partitioned table before, that's why I asked :-)

Comment: you most likely saw this link already - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables - in the same section of documentation  you will find all you need to start with :o)

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right and the tables can be partitioned by transaction_date.  Please note that there are only two types of table partitioning in BigQuery:

Tables partitioned by ingestion time: Tables partitioned based on the data's ingestion (load) date or arrival date.
Partitioned tables: Tables that are partitioned based on a TIMESTAMP or DATE column.

Thus, you can not consider other columns for partitioning.

For more details, please refer to [Link 1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data), 
[Link 2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) and
[Link 3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition)

As an alternative to partitioned tables, you can shard tables using a time-based naming approach such as [PREFIX]_YYYYMMDD. This is referred to as creating date-sharded tables. Sharding is one specific type of partitioning, namely horizontal partitioning.